# Rename an index in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to rename an index in Laravel 5.

In a previous migration a column was created for table named `a` like so:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('foo')->index('blah');
```

I want to rename the index so that it uses the default Laravel notation.

i.e. I want to rename the `blah` index to `a_blah`.

I know how to rename a normal column, like so:

```
$table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
```

But the documentation does not mention how to rename indexes.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

It seems that Laravel does not support this natively. Please upvote the issue:

https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/443

Comment: I think Laravel doesn't support any method for renaming index, you should drop the old index `blah` and make new one with desired name `a_blah`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Laravel 5.6** now supports renaming indexes:

```
$table->renameIndex('from', 'to')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#renaming-indexes

**Old Answer for Laravel <= 5.5**

As @KuKec mentioned, it seems Laravel does not have native support for renaming indexes. But you can use raw SQL. For example in MySQL it would be like so:

```
DB::statement('RENAME INDEX old_index TO new_index');
```

This would also likely be more efficient than dropping and re-indexing (especially on large databases).

I have also created an issue for the feature request so this is better supported. Please upvote it here: https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/443

Comment: PostgreSQL: `\DB::statement('ALTER INDEX old_index RENAME TO new_index');`

Answer (score 3):

I think Laravel doesn't support any method for renaming index, you should drop the old index `blah`

```
$table->dropIndex('blah');
```

and make new one with desired name `a_blah`.

```
$table->index('foo', 'a_blah');
```

Comment: It's a shame Laravel does not support this natively as this is very inefficient. Please upvote the feature request: https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/443

Comment: renaming indexes is now supported on Laravel 5.6 (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should first:

```
$table->dropIndex('your_full_name_index')
```

then do

```
$table->index('new_index_name')
```

Comment: I accepted KuKec answer because he had the answer first as a comment. Sorry